# Is an "If statement" the exact same as a "Switch statement" in Java?

Tags: java

Performance aside, I'm wondering if there are certain situations where only an If statement can be used and not a Switch statement and vice versa?

As in, are they completely interchangeable? Could I swap an entire section of code From Switch statements to If statements and vice versa if I so desired or would that break specific programs?

Not that I would want to but just theoretically and out of curiosity as I am new to Coding and have been wondering this.

I couldn't really find the answer I was looking for so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are fundamentally different in what they can do - `if` statements can check any logic you can distil down to a `boolean` value in some way, while `switch` statements compare exact values for each case - see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for details.

> An if-then-else statement can test expressions based on ranges of values or conditions, whereas a switch statement tests expressions based only on a single integer, enumerated value, or String object.

This means if you want to do more complex logic than 'does this value equal this number, enum or string' for each case, you need `if` statements (or some other way of managing flow) rather than a `switch`.

A simple example is checking if a number is over 10 but under 9000.

```
if (value > 10 && value < 9000) {
    ...
}
```

Converting this to a switch statement would mean doing something insane like have a case for every possible value over 10 but under 9000)

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. I hadn't gotten into more complex logic yet so I couldn't for the life of me understand why the If statement even existed. Thanks for the quick and thorough answer!

Comment: @Graver It's worth noting that there are other differences too - switch statements have fall-through (without `break`s, the flow falls into future cases) - this is pretty hard to emulate with `if` statements (and is a reason `switch` is often left out of newer languages - it's semantics are awkward and easy to make mistakes with - it's main advantage is that it's easy to optimise).